# Bash compiling Java classes and JARs

Tags: java, bash, unix, classpath, javac

I am attempting to write a script that will automate a few tasks that I do regularly. The folder structure of my files is like so:

```
./
sampleScript.sh
src/SampleProgram.java
```

In addition to this, my Java program relies on the `ojdbc6.jar` file, which resides in `~/sampleFolder/lib`.

I have attempted to compile and run the Java program in my script like so:

```
javac -cp "$CLASSPATH:~/sampleFolder/lib/ojdbc6.jar:./src" src/SampleProgram.java
java -cp "$CLASSPATH:~/sampleFolder/lib/ojdbc6.jar:./src" SampleProgram
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. It seems to fail at the step in my program that checks for the `ojdbc6.jar` dependency. What's the proper way to assign my `-cp` based on this folder structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must keep `~` outside quote so that shell can expand it:

```
javac -cp "$CLASSPATH":~/sampleFolder/lib/ojdbc6.jar:./src src/SampleProgram.java
java  -cp "$CLASSPATH":~/sampleFolder/lib/ojdbc6.jar:./src SampleProgram
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but my program still seems to fail at this step: `try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }` with the message `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Comment: This should work. Aren't you getting any error in `javac` now? You can also try giving full path to jar file like: `java  -cp "$CLASSPATH":/home/user/sampleFolder/lib/ojdbc6.jar:./src SampleProgram`

Comment: I'd suggest `$HOME` over `~` for a number of reasons not least of which is that it expands in quotes.

Comment: @anubhava @EtanReisner thanks, expanding the full path as well as using `$HOME` worked. Based on my folder structure, is including `./src` still necessary for both `javac` and `java`?

Comment: Seems that I can take it out of `javac` since it is not needed to compile, but I have to leave it in for `java` as the `SampleProgram.class` file resides in `./src`. Thanks again!